# change views height in Keyboard extension (iPhone X)

Tags: swift, swift4, iphone-x, ios-keyboard-extension

I have following problem: I build a keyboard extension, a alternative keyboard to the system keyboard. In all older iPhone models it works fine, but at the iPhone X it doesn't. My problem is, the height of the keyboard's view is decreasing from 216px (iPhone 8 ,8+ , ...) to 141px (iPhone X). Because lower height, my keyboard buttons are now smaller, to small for good user usability.

I did used a .xib file to create the UI, I add all UI - Items programmatically.

[image: iPhone 8]
[image: iPhone X]

### my Question

Is it posible to get more space (height) for the keyboard extension view (specially for the iPhone X) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solve my problem. I found following paragraph in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html):

> You can adjust the height of your custom keyboard’s primary view using Auto Layout. By default, a custom keyboard is sized to match the system keyboard, according to screen size and device orientation. A custom keyboard’s width is always set by the system to equal the current screen width. To adjust a custom keyboard’s height, change its primary view's height constraint.
>
> The following code lines show how you might define and add such a constraint:

```
CGFloat _expandedHeight = 500;
NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = 
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.view 
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight 
                                 relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                    toItem: nil 
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute 
                                multiplier: 0.0 
                                  constant: _expandedHeight];
[self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraint];
```

### Swift 4

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 300)
        self.view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
    }
```

Comment: Should this be added to the `UIInputViewController` or its subview?

Comment: Note that this causes a layout constraint error for me. Setting the height constraint priority to `999` eliminates the error but still applies the height.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the constraints to `ViewDidLoad` method solves the issue.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 220)
        self.view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
        setupKeyboard()
```

Note: Creating a subview generates a memory warning.